# revive vs remind

Tags: grammaticality, verbs, auxiliary-verbs

Are revive and remind interchangeable in the following sentences:
(1). This JP anime has revived she of her childhood.
(2). This JP anime has reminded she of her childhood.

Comment: Have you looked up _revive_ in a dictionary? Why do you think it may be interchangeable with _remind_, which has a different meaning and very different usage? By the way, in both sentences, _her_ should be used instead of _she_ :)

Comment: "revive somebody of something"?? This phrase seems ungrammatical.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because you are asking for dictionary definitions of two words that are very, very different from each other.  This question will probably be flagged and closed unless you provide some reason for how these words could be confused.  Do you have an example you have come across where they seemed interchangeable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> (1). This JP anime has revived she of her childhood.
>   (2). This JP anime has reminded she of her childhood.

No, they are not interchangeable. They have different meanings and take different complements.

We could make the two sentences' meanings somewhat close:

> This anime has revived her childhood memories.
>   This anime has reminded her of her childhood.

Notice that I changed **she** to **her**, because it's an "[object pronoun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_pronoun)" in your sentences.

"Anime" is the subject (the thing that acts), "she" is the object (the thing that is being acted upon), and some English pronouns change their form when used as objects.

Comment: @CopperKettle: Interestingly, you've changed the object pronoun to a POSSESSIVE pronoun "her" in the first sentence, to make it work, but it's spelled the same as the regular object pronoun "her" in the second sentence. That's something you might want to notice, Kitty.

Comment: I am sorry Brian, because I can't understand what you mean. Please help me.